# D/SingleLive: Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes

Tags: android, kotlin

I can't use more than one myobserve how can i solve?

First Observe

```
   private fun warehousesKaynakDepo() {
       var listKaynakDepo: ArrayList<String>
       var mutableMap: MutableMap<String, String>
       viewModel.getDataDemakDepolar(apiUrl)
       viewModel.liveDataDepolar.myObserve(
           viewLifecycleOwner,
           success = { list ->
               listKaynakDepo = ArrayList()
               mutableMap = mutableMapOf()
               mutableMapDepo = mutableMapOf()
               mutableMapDepoKod = mutableMapOf()

               for (i in list) {
                   listKaynakDepo.add(i.DEPOAD)
                   mutableMap[i.DEPOAD] = i.DEPOKOD
                   mutableMapDepoKod[i.DEPOKOD] = i.DEPOAD


               }
               val depoArrayAdapter = activity?.let {
                   ArrayAdapter(it, R.layout.view_spinner_dropdown_item, listKaynakDepo)
               }!!
               println("depolar :${mutableMap.entries}")
               binding.spinnerKaynakDepoSec.setAdapter(depoArrayAdapter)
               binding.spinnerKaynakDepoSec.onItemClickListener =
                   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, _, position, _ ->
                       depoAd = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
                       depoKod = mutableMap[depoAd].toString()
                       hedefDepo = ""
                       hedefDepoKod= ""
                       targetWarehouse()

                   }
           },
           empty = {
               listKaynakDepo = ArrayList()
               binding.spinnerKaynakDepoSec.setAdapter(null)
               toastWarning(str(R.string.depoyok))
               binding.emptyView.visible()
           },
           error = {
               listKaynakDepo = ArrayList()
               binding.spinnerKaynakDepoSec.setAdapter(null)
               toastError(it)
           }
       )
   }
```

Second Observe

```
 private fun targetWarehouse(){
        var mutableMapHedef: MutableMap<String, String>
        var listHedefDepo: ArrayList<String>
        viewModel.getDataDemakHedefDepolar(apiUrl, kaynakDepoKod)
        viewModel.liveDataHedefDepolar.myObserve(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            success = { list ->
                listHedefDepo = ArrayList()
                mutableMapHedef = mutableMapOf()
                for (i in list) {
                    listHedefDepo.add(i.DEPOAD)
                    mutableMapHedef[i.DEPOAD] = i.DEPOKOD
                }
                val arrayHedefAdapter = activity?.let {
                    ArrayAdapter(it, R.layout.view_spinner_dropdown_item, listHedefDepo)
                }!!

                detayRowBinding.spinnerHedefDepoSec.setAdapter(arrayHedefAdapter)
                detayRowBinding.spinnerHedefDepoSec.onItemClickListener =
                    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, _, position, _ ->
                        depoAd = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
                        depoKod = mutableMapHedef[depoAd].toString()
                        view?.hideKeyboard()
                    }

            },
            empty = {
                listHedefDepo = ArrayList()
                detayRowBinding.spinnerHedefDepoSec.setAdapter(null)
                toastWarning(str(R.string.depoyok))
            },
            error = {
                listHedefDepo = ArrayList()
                detayRowBinding.spinnerHedefDepoSec.setAdapter(null)
                toastError(it)
            }
        )
    }
```

The second observe opens inside the dialog ;

```
private fun showAskAmountDialog(value:String) {
        showDialog(object : ViewConvertListener<DemakRafTransferDetailsBinding> {
            override fun provideViewBinding(
                inflater: LayoutInflater,
                container: ViewGroup?
            ): DemakRafTransferDetailsBinding { return DemakRafTransferDetailsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false) }

            override fun convertView(vb: DemakRafTransferDetailsBinding, dialog: BaseMyDialog<DemakRafTransferDetailsBinding>) {
                detayRowBinding = vb
                vb.edtAmount.setText(value)


                vb.imgBarcodeHedef.onClick {
                    binding.barcodeView.pauseAndWait()
                    showBarcodeDialog {
                        vb.addHedef.setText(it)
                        hedefRaf=it
                    }
                }

                vb.spinnerHedefDepoSec.onClick {
                    targetWarehouse()
                }

                vb.btnCancel.onClick {
                    dialog.dismiss()
                    binding.barcodeView.resume()
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

First Observe Works (Lists data) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPbZ6.jpg

And Second (in dialog) not work (Not Lists) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwnZQ.jpg

i tried to solve it but i couldn't

I want to list it on the dialog screen too, I couldn't find how to do it.

Could it be a problem with the click event?

Comment: What is `myobserve`?